# Building mutiple Artifacts for Vaadin-Application [Gradle]

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, vaadin, vaadin8

I am currently working on a Vaadin 8 project using the gradle vaadin-plugin.

In the project there are 3 SourceSets main,a and b. The later two exclude some views and features. Is it possible to build 3 Artifcats via gradle one for each sourceSet. I tried modifying the war task but that broke the views.

```
conf{
    aCompile.extendsFrom compile
    aRuntime.extendsFrom runtime

    bCompile.extendsFrom compile
    bRuntime.extendsFrom runtime
}
 sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/main/generated']
        }
    }
    a{
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/main/generated']
            exclude 'com/exmaple/features/b'
            exclude 'com/exmaple/views/b'
        }

        compileClasspath += main.output
        runtimeClasspath += main.output

        output.resourcesDir = 'build/resources/main'
        output.classesDir = 'build/classes/java/main'
    }
    b{
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/main/generated']
            exclude 'com/exmaple/features/a'
            exclude 'com/exmaple/views/a'
        }
        compileClasspath += main.output
        runtimeClasspath += main.output

        output.resourcesDir = 'build/resources/main'
        output.classesDir = 'build/classes/java/main'
    }
}
task aWar(type: War) {
    appendix = "a"
    from sourceSets.a.output
}

task bWar(type: War) {
    appendix = "b"
    from sourceSets.b.output
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_management.html#sec:declaring_artifacts you should be able to declare an artifact for every source set.

In your case it would look something like this:

```
task aWar(type: War, dependsOn: classes) {
  baseName = 'a.war'
  classpath = project.configurations.aRuntime
}

task bWar(type: War, dependsOn: classes) {
  baseName = 'b.war'
  classpath = project.configurations.bRuntime
}

artifacts {
   archives aWar, bWar
}
```

The WAR task also allows you to include/exclude classes using a regexp. Checkout more at https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.War.html